# What is the simplest way to export CouchDB information to CSV?

Tags: csv, export, couchdb

What would be the simplest way to export a CouchDB database of documents (identical structure) to CSV?

I'm guessing it would involve writing a view and manually parsing each document serially using something like PHP, C# or Python.

But is there a simpler way or something already existing I can make use of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to generate the CSV directly from CouchDB, i.e. without PHP/C#/Python, using a list function. See http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List and http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/transforming.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks thats great; Not sure how i managed to miss that when I was poking through the documentation :o)

Comment: Link is dead.  It's good practice to summarise the contents of the link so the answer remains useful even after the link has gone dead.

Answer (score 2):

I made this : https://gist.github.com/3026004 , it takes the first 100 documents as sample for headers, and it supports nested hashes and arrays.