# Export CouchDB database to CSV

Tags: csv, couchdb

I'm quite RDB use and have no experience about REST or programming..

I'm usually working with MSSQL and excel...

There is some database on couchdb that I want to export to Excel.

How can I export database to csv?

Here's example of first document's source.

```
{
   "_id": "0188d98de825528ce9c980f65d0024cc",
   "_rev": "1-046e405f344709e96ee1ef51464871d1",
   "contributors": null,
   "truncated": false,
   "text": "Plume test1",
   "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
   "id": 311079203028209660,
   "favorite_count": 0,
   "source": "<a href=\"http://www.myplume.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\">Plume for Android</a>",
   "retweeted": false,
   "coordinates": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates": [
           126.897899,
           37.535298
       ]
   },
   "entities": {
       "symbols": [
       ],
       "user_mentions": [
       ],
       "hashtags": [
       ],
       "urls": [
       ]
   },
   "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
   "id_str": "311079203028209664",
   "retweet_count": 0,
   "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
   "favorited": false,
   "user": {
       "id": 20825023,
       "id_str": "20825023"
   },
   "geo": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates": [
           37.535298,
           126.897899
       ]
   },
   "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
   "lang": "et",
   "created_at": "Mon Mar 11 11:40:36 +0000 2013",
   "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
   "place": null
}
```

I've try https://gist.github.com/xalakox/3026004 but doesn't work.

Desire exported csv is something like

```
created at, text, source, coordinates1, coordinates2
Mon Mar 11 11:40:36 +0000 2013,Plume test1,Plume for Android,126.897899,37.535298
Mon Mar 11 11:40:36 +0000 2013,Plume test1,Plume for Android,126.897899,37.535298
Mon Mar 11 11:40:36 +0000 2013,Plume test1,Plume for Android,126.897899,37.535298
Mon Mar 11 11:40:36 +0000 2013,Plume test1,Plume for Android,126.897899,37.535298
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the simplest way to export couchdb information to CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871409/whats-the-simplest-way-to-export-couchdb-information-to-csv)

Comment: You said you tried to reuse an existing `list`. However, a `list` must be applied to a `view`, have you written a `view` yet?

Answer (score 1):

Use a browser tool to get the CSV from the JSON result. Here is the source:

````
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>JSON to CSV</title>
<meta name="og:title" content="JSON to CSV" />

<meta name="description" content="A simple, in-browser JSON viewer, and CSV converter." />
<meta name="og:description" content="A simple, in-browser JSON viewer and CSV converter." />

<meta name="author" content="Eric Mill" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@konklone" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://konklone.io/json/" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/json/favicon.png" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://konklone.io/json/" />

<!--
redirect users to the https version of the website.
but: only check when on the production domain.
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var enforce = "konklone.io";
  if ((enforce == window.location.host) && (window.location.protocol != "https:"))
    window.location.protocol = "https";
</script>

<!-- jquery, jquery-csv,bootstrap -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>
<script src="assets/jquery.csv.js"></script>
<link href="assets/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- site styles and JS -->
<link href="assets/site.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/github.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="assets/site.js"></script>
<script src="assets/highlight.pack.js"></script>

<script>
  var excerptRows = 7;
  var input;
  var url;
  var lastSaved;

  // function log(msg) {
  //   return $(".console").removeClass("error").html(msg);
  // }

  // function error(msg) {
  //   return log(msg).addClass("error");
  // }

  function doJSON() {
    // just in case
    $(".drop").hide();

    // get input JSON, try to parse it
    var newInput = $(".json textarea").val();
    if (newInput == input) return;

    input = newInput;
    if (!input) {
      // wipe the rendered version too
      $(".json code").html("");
      return;
    }

    var json = jsonFrom(input);

    // if succeeded, prettify and highlight it
    // highlight shows when textarea loses focus
    if (json) {
      // Reset any error message from previous failed parses.
      $("div.error").hide();
      $("div.warning").show();

      var pretty = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 2);
      $(".json code").html(pretty);
      if (pretty.length < (50 * 1024))
        hljs.highlightBlock($(".json code").get(0));

      // convert to CSV, make available
      doCSV(json);
    } else {
      // Show error.
      $("div.warning").hide();
      $("div.error").show();
      $(".json code").html("");
    }

    // Either way, update the error-reporting link to include the latest.
    setErrorReporting(null, input);

    return true;
  }

  // show rendered JSON
  function showJSON(rendered) {
    console.log("ordered to show JSON: " + rendered);
    if (rendered) {
      if ($(".json code").html()) {
        console.log("there's code to show, showing...");
        $(".json .rendered").show();
        $(".json .editing").hide();
      }
    } else {
      $(".json .rendered").hide();
      $(".json .editing").show().focus();
    }
  }

  function showCSV(rendered) {
    if (rendered) {
      if ($(".csv table").html()) {
        $(".csv .rendered").show();
        $(".csv .editing").hide();
      }
    } else {
      $(".csv .rendered").hide();
      $(".csv .editing").show().focus();
    }
  }

  // takes an array of flat JSON objects, converts them to arrays
  // renders them into a small table as an example
  function renderCSV(objects) {
    var rows = $.csv.fromObjects(objects, {justArrays: true});
    if (rows.length < 1) return;

    // find CSV table
    var table = $(".csv table")[0];
    $(table).html("");

    // render header row
    var thead = document.createElement("thead");
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var header = rows[0];
    for (field in header) {
      var th = document.createElement("th");
      $(th).html(header[field])
      tr.appendChild(th);
    }
    thead.appendChild(tr);

    // render body of table
    var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
    for (var i=1; i<rows.length; i++) {
      tr = document.createElement("tr");
      for (field in rows[i]) {
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        $(td)
          .html(rows[i][field])
          .attr("title", rows[i][field]);
        tr.appendChild(td);
      }
      tbody.appendChild(tr);
    }

    table.appendChild(thead);
    table.appendChild(tbody);
  }

  function doCSV(json) {
    // 1) find the primary array to iterate over
    // 2) for each item in that array, recursively flatten it into a tabular object
    // 3) turn that tabular object into a CSV row using jquery-csv
    var inArray = arrayFrom(json);

    var outArray = [];
    for (var row in inArray)
        outArray[outArray.length] = parse_object(inArray[row]);

    $("span.rows.count").text("" + outArray.length);

    var csv = $.csv.fromObjects(outArray);
    // excerpt and render first 10 rows
    renderCSV(outArray.slice(0, excerptRows));
    showCSV(true);

    // show raw data if people really want it
    $(".csv textarea").val(csv);

    // download link to entire CSV as data
    // thanks to https://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU/
    // and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side
    var uri = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(csv);
    $(".csv a.download").attr("href", uri);
  }

  // loads original pasted JSON from textarea, saves to anonymous gist
  // rate-limiting means this could easily fail with a 403.
  function saveJSON() {
    if (!input) return false;
    if (input == lastSaved) return false;

    // save a permalink to an anonymous gist
    var gist = {
      description: "test",
      public: false,
      files: {
        "source.json": {
            "content": input
        }
      }
    };

    // TODO: show spinner/msg while this happens

    console.log("Saving to an anonymous gist...");
    $.post(
      'https://api.github.com/gists',
      JSON.stringify(gist)
    ).done(function(data, status, xhr) {

      // take new Gist id, make permalink
      setPermalink(data.id);

      // send analytics event
      Events.permalink();

      // mark what we last saved
      lastSaved = input;

      // update error-reporting link, including permalink
      setErrorReporting(data.id, input);

      console.log("Remaining this hour: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("X-RateLimit-Remaining"));

    }).fail(function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
      console.log(xhr);

      // send analytics event
      Events.permalink_error(status);

      // TODO: gracefully handle rate limit errors
      // if (status == 403)

      // TODO: show when saving will be available
      // e.g. "try again in 5 minutes"
      // var reset = xhr.getResponseHeader("X-RateLimit-Reset");
      // var date = new Date();
      // date.setTime(parseInt(reset) * 1000);
      // use http://momentjs.com/ to say "in _ minutes"

    });

    return false;
  }

  // Updates the error-reporting link to include current details.
  //
  // If the passed-in `id` is not null, a permalink is included.
  // If the passed-in `id` is null, then no permalink is included.
  // (Needed explicitly because the current URL doesn't always refer
  // to a permalink related to the current value of the textarea.)
  //
  // The current body of the textarea will be encoded into the URI,
  // to pre-populate the GitHub issue template, but only if the body
  // is < 7KB (7,168). GitHub's nginx server rejects query strings
  // longer than ~8KB.
  //
  // If no `id` is given, and content is too long, the URL will
  // encode only a title, and no body.
  function setErrorReporting(id, content) {
    var base = "https://github.com/konklone/json/issues/new";

    var title = "Error parsing some specific JSON";

    var body = "I'm having an issue converting this JSON:\n\n";
    if (id) body += (
      window.location.protocol + "//" +
      window.location.host + window.location.pathname +
      "?id=" + id + "\n\n"
    );

    if (content.length <= (7 * 1024))
      body += ("```json\n" + content + "\n```");

    var finalUrl = base + "?title=" + encodeURIComponent(title) +
      "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(body);

    $(".error a.report").attr("href", finalUrl);

    // console.log("Updated error reporting link to:" + finalUrl);
    return true;
  }

  // given a valid gist ID, set the permalink to use it
  function setPermalink(id) {
    if (history && history.pushState)
      history.pushState({id: id}, null, "?id=" + id);

    // log("Permalink created! (Copy from the location bar.)")
  }

  // check query string for gist ID
  function loadPermalink() {
    var id = getParam("id");
    if (!id) return;

    $.get('https://api.github.com/gists/' + id,
      function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log("Remaining this hour: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("X-RateLimit-Remaining"));

        var input = data.files["source.json"].content;
        $(".json textarea").val(input);
        doJSON();
        showJSON(true);
      }
    ).fail(function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
      console.log("Error fetching anonymous gist!");
      console.log(xhr);
      console.log(status);
      console.log(errorThrown);
    });
  }

  $(function() {

    $(".json textarea").blur(function() {showJSON(true);});
    $(".json pre").click(function() {showJSON(false)});
    $(".csv textarea").blur(function() {showCSV(true);})
    $(".csv .raw").click(function() {
      showCSV(false);
      $(".csv textarea").focus().select();
      return false;
    })

    // if there's no CSV to download, don't download anything.
    // also, log an analytics event.
    $(".csv a.download").click(function() {
      var data = $(".csv textarea").val();
      if (data) {
        Events.download(data.length);
        return true;
      } else
        return false;
    });

    // Both elements are present on page-load, so use normal click handler.
    $(".save a, .error a.save").click(saveJSON);

    // transform the JSON whenever it's pasted/edited
    $(".json textarea")
      .on('paste', function() {
        // delay the showing so the paste is pasted by then
        setTimeout(function() {
          doJSON();
          $(".json textarea").blur();
        }, 1);
      })
      .keyup(doJSON); // harmless to repeat doJSON

    // go away
    $("body").click(function() {
      $(".drop").hide();
    });

    $(document)
      .on("dragenter", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".drop").show();
      })
      .on("dragover", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
      })
      .on("dragend", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".drop").hide();
      })
      .on("drop", function(e) {
        $(".drop").hide();

        if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer) {
          if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(ev) {
              console.log(ev.target.result);
              $(".json textarea").val(ev.target.result);

              setTimeout(function() {
                doJSON();
                $(".json textarea").blur();
              }, 1);
            }

            reader.readAsText(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0]);
          }
        }
      });

    // highlight CSV on click
    $(".csv textarea").click(function() {$(this).focus().select();});

    loadPermalink();
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Convert JSON to CSV</h1>

<section class="json">

  <p>
    <span class="instruction editing">
      Paste your JSON below.
    </span>

    <span class="instruction rendered">
      Click your JSON below to edit.
    </span>

    <span class="save">
      <a href="#">Create a permalink</a> any time.
    </span>

    <span>
      Please <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/konklone/json/issues">report bugs and send feedback</a> on GitHub.
    </span>

    <span>
      Made by <a href="https://twitter.com/konklone">@konklone.</a>
    </span>
  </p>

  <div class="areas">
    <textarea class="editing"></textarea>
    <pre class="rendered"><code></code></pre>
    <div class="drop">DROP JSON HERE</div>
  </div>

  <div class="warning">
    Extremely large files may cause trouble &mdash; the conversion is done inside your browser.
  </div>

  <div class="error">
    There was an error parsing this JSON. If you're sure this JSON is valid, please
    <a class="report" target="_blank"
      href="https://github.com/konklone/json/issues/new">
      file an issue</a>.
    You can
    <a class="save" href="#">create a permalink to the error</a>
    any time.
  </div>
</section>

<section class="csv">

  <p>
    <span class="rendered">
      Below are the first few rows (<span class="rows count"></span> total).

      <a download="result.csv" href="#" class="download">
        Download the entire CSV</a>,

      or <a href="#" class="raw">show the raw data</a>.
    </span>

    <span class="editing">
      Your JSON will appear below as a table.
    </span>
  </p>

  <div class="areas">
    <textarea class="editing" readonly></textarea>
    <div class="table rendered">
      <table></table>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<footer>
<p>
  Thanks to <a href="https://twitter.com/benbalter">@benbalter</a> for help, and to <a href="https://twitter.com/onyxfish">@onyxfish</a> for the amazing <a href="https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/in2csv.html">csvkit</a>.
</p>
</footer>

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-252618-16', 'konklone.io');
  ga('set', 'forceSSL', true);
  ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

</body>
</html>
````

**References**

- [Convert JSON to CSV](https://konklone.io/json/)
- [Making JSON as simple as a spreadsheet : Sunlight Foundation](https://sunlightfoundation.com/2014/03/11/making-json-as-simple-as-a-spreadsheet/)